# MVC4: Display jQuery model popup in view when error occurred?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying show a jQuery model popup when error occurred in controller and display a same view where controller trying return.

Now I working on  `Home/Index.cshtml` and controller `[HttpGet] Index()` controller method. If any error occurred in Index() method display jQuery popup in view Index.cshtml.

How can we do that?

### Update

As `@MelanciaUK`, I have implemented like this.

```
  @{
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.errorsOccurred))
        {
           <text>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(function () {
                      $.fancybox.open({
                              'content' : $("#divForm").html()
                   });
                });
              </script>
            </text>
         }
      }
       @using (Html.BeginForm())
       {
                          ----
                          ----
       }
        <div id="divForm" style="display:none">
            An error has occurred on the page.
        </div>

    @section Scripts {  
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fancybox")
    }
```

`.fancybox.open` is never called and skipping from the executing in `@using (Html.BeginForm())`. I just want show `fancybox`. What was the wrong here?

Comment: This would usually be done as a result of an AJAX call; unless you're saying you want to display it on pageload?  Which do you want?

Comment: thats true.. I need on pageload.

Comment: jQuery modal dialogs are `autoOpen`-ed by default.  See the documentation http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-autoOpen

Comment: Store the error(s) message(s) into a variable, and on the View, test it for any content. If so, open the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using *Fancybox* and not the *jQuery UI Dialog*, I've re-written my answer.
It's been tested on *Visual Studio* and works perfectly.
Have it a go:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitMyForm()
{
    // Forcing an error.
    ViewBag.errorsOccurred = "An error has occurred!";

    return View();
 }
```

**Razor View (_Layout):**

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divForm").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

**Razor View (Index):**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitMyForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" name="myInput" id="myInput" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

**Razor View (SubmitMyForm):**

```
@{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.errorsOccurred))
    {
        <text>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $.fancybox.open({ "content": "@ViewBag.errorsOccurred" });
                });
            </script>
        </text>
    }
}

<div id="divForm"></div>
```

Comment: I've re-written my answer.